# How to print main, customer and duplicate copy in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

How to print first time **Main Copy**
second time **Customer Copy**
third or more time **Duplicate Copy**

My requirement is as in the image below:

[image: Main Copy, Customer Copy, Duplicate Copy]

Comment: Which version of crystal reports are you using? Please only use relevant tags!  Also, is there any difference between the versions other than the text in the top right corner saying **Main/Customer/Duplicate Copy**?

Comment: I have worked in all version. Now  work on **crystal-reports-xi**

Comment: Pass a parameter to your report. Then create a formula for the type of copy based on the passed parameter.

Comment: plz details answer me.

Comment: Post snippet of your code where you are creating and display report. This will help people to suggest you with exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VB Code**

At first do Import

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Sub ShowReport(ByVal MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument, ByVal filterstring As String, ByVal CrystalReportViewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer)
    Dim myLogonInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
    Dim myTable As Table
    For Each myTable In MyReport.Database.Tables
        myLogonInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo
        'myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Application.StartupPath & "\" & "data.mdb"
        myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = My.Settings.RptserverPath.ToString
        myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = My.Settings.Database.ToString
        myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = My.Settings.DBUser.ToString
        myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = My.Settings.DBPass.ToString
        myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myLogonInfo)
    Next myTable
End Sub

Private Sub SimpleButton4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton4.Click
    For reportType As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New RecipeWithOutCostingSheet
        MyReport.SetParameterValue("paramReportType", reportType)
        PrintReport(MyReport, filterstring, CrystalReportViewer1, PrintDialog1)
    Next
End Sub
```

**Crystal report Formula Create** formula name **paramReportType**

```
Select {?paramReportType}
Case  1 :
    "Main Copy"
Case  2 :
    "Customer Copy"
Default :
    "Duplicate Copy"
```

Put on your Report Location.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
Dim rpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        rpt.Load("<report name>")
        rpt.SetDataSource(your datasource)
        For reportType As Integer = 1 To 3
            rpt.SetParameterValue("paramReportType", reportType)
            ' show your report in a dialog window
            ShowReport(rpt)
        Next


Public Sub ShowReport(ByRef oRpt As Object)
    Using frm As New ReportViewer
        With frm
            .Icon = frmMain.Icon
            .Report = oRpt
            .ShowDialog()
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```

Inside ReportViewer form (with 1 CrystalReportViewer control named crv)

```
Public Class ReportViewer

Dim oReport As Object






Public WriteOnly Property Report() As Object
    Set(ByVal value As Object)
        oReport = value
    End Set
End Property







Private Sub ReportViewer_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

        crv.ReportSource = oRpt
    Catch ex As Exception
        Msgbox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

In your report, create a parameter value named paramReportType with a type of Number.

Then, also inside your report, create a formula field (I'm using Basic syntax)

```
select case {?paramReportType}
case 1
    formula = "Main Copy"
case 2
    formula = "Customer Copy"
case 3
    formula = "Duplicate Copy"
end select
```

Then add the formula field to your report, instead of a Text object.

Comment: Dear @F0r3v3r-A-N00b, Bro- Thanks your Support this is work. Actually I want third or more printing time showing **Duplicate Copy**. But it is Every  Print command time showing (Main, Customer, Duplicate). The first Print command Main copy and customer copy has been printed
and next or more command only have been print Duplicate Copy. plz fix this.

Comment: Yes see my update in the select case. The third option should be 3.

Comment: In that case, you need to set some form of flag or print count in your database.